# Ecto raw query string interpolation not working

Tags: elixir, ecto

The string interpolation fails with this query:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(
  MyApp.Repo,
  "CREATE INDEX zip_code_trgm_idx ON $1 USING GIN (zip_code gin_trgm_ops);",
  ["locations_zipcodes"]
)

[debug] QUERY ERROR db=0.0ms queue=19.5ms
CREATE INDEX zip_code_trgm_idx ON $1 USING GIN (zip_code gin_trgm_ops); ["locations_zipcodes"]
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "$1"
```

But works fine if I manually interpolate.